# Host a website in dialog and ensure the communication with the google sheet and the backend

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, iframe, cors, add-on

I'm making a Google Sheets add-on. The add-on opens a modeless dialog which hosts [www.myfrontend.com](http://www.myfrontend.com) which uses [www.mybackend.com](http://www.mybackend.com) as the backend.

#### 1. Use createHtmlOutput and iframe

To realize this, one way is to use `iframe` as follows:

```
var htmlOutput = HtmlService
    .createHtmlOutput('<iframe src="https://www.myfrontend.com/#/home" style="width: 100%; height: 800px; border: none;"></iframe>'
    .setWidth(600)
    .setHeight(800);
SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(htmlOutput, 'My add-on');
```

By this approach, myfrontend.com can be shown in the dialog and call mybackend.com without any problem. However, it seems that `google` is not available in myfrontend.com; I cannot call `google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(res).withFailureHandler(rej)...` in myfrontend.com. As a consequence, myfrontend.com cannot communicate with the Google Sheet.

#### 2. Use createHtmlOutputFromFile

Another way is to have another file like `production.html` in Apps Script, and use it as follows:

```
var htmlOutput = HtmlService
    .createHtmlOutputFromFile('production')
    .setWidth(600)
    .setHeight(800);
SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(htmlOutput, 'My add-on');
```

`production.html` is copied from `build/index.html` of myfrontend.com, and changed slightly:

```
<!doctype html>
  <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8"/>
      <base href="https://www.myfrontend.com/">
      <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico"/>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1"/>
      <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff"/>
      <meta name="description" content="Web site created using create-react-app"/>
      <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/logo192.png"/><link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json"/>
      <meta charset="utf-8"/><meta charset="UTF-8"/><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge"/>
      <title>myApp</title>
      <script>window.location.hash = "#/home"</script>
      ... ...
```

By this approach, myfrontend.com can be shown in the dialog and it seems that `google` and `google.script.run` are available in myfrontend.com. However, when we sign in in myfrontend.com, the browser returns a CORS error:

```
[Error] Origin https://n-5fydpzckmar5yncflnjytuyfcusdcfogmgc2eti-1lu-script.googleusercontent.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. Status code: 204
[Error] XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.mybackend.com/httpOnly/signin due to access control checks.
```

In `app.js` of [www.backend.com](http://www.backend.com), I have already enabled the CORS as follows, but the error still exists:

```
app.use(cors({
  origin: [/\.mybackend\.com$/, /\.myfrontend\.com$/, /localhost(:[0-9]*)?$/, /\.live\.com$/, "https://onedrive.live.com", /https:\/\/[\w-]+\.script\.googleusercontent\.com/],
  credentials: true,
}));
```

So does anyone know what's the correct way to host a website in modeless dialog, ensure the communication to the google sheet by `google.script.run` and the communication to the backend?

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your situation, when you modify `SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(htmlOutput, 'My add-on');` to `SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(htmlOutput.setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL), 'My add-on');`, what result will you obtain? But, I'm not sure whether this is the direction for resolving your current issue. So, I posted this as a comment. I apologize for this.

Comment: @Tanaike my tests show that `htmlOutput.setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL` does not help on any of the above two approaches.

Comment: Thank you for replying and testing it. I deeply apologize that my comment was not useful.

Comment: @Tanaike no problem, thank you.

Comment: XframeOptions Allow all(or CSP allowing "https://n-5fydpzckmar5yncflnjytuyfcusdcfogmgc2eti-1lu-script.googleusercontent.com") would also work, but it needs to be set on "www.mybackend.com"

Comment: @TheMaster I have control over www.mybackend.com, could you tell me what I need to set up to make XframeOptions Allow all work?

Comment: 1. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/frame-ancestors 2. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options Do note the security implications. I also don't see how your frontend calls the backend... I'm guessing it's by loading the  backend sign in page judging by the url. If not, You need to provide the backend framework.

Comment: On closer look, may be it's just the regex... :) Added an another answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex

```
/https:\/\/[\w-]+\.script\.googleusercontent\.com/
```

won't match

```
https://n-5fydpzckmar5yncflnjytuyfcusdcfogmgc2eti-1lu-script.googleusercontent.com
```

Note that there's no `.` between  `https://n-5fydpzckmar5yncflnjytuyfcusdcfogmgc2eti-1lu-` and `script.googleusercontent.com`

The correct regex would be

```
/https:\/\/[\w\-]+script\.googleusercontent\.com/
```

Comment: Thank you. My regex was wrong. After fixing it, I could follow the approach without `iframe`; It seems that `setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL)` is not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`window.postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) to communicate.

##### Sample snippets:

###### modal.html

```html
<script>
window.addEventListener('message',e =>{
  if(e.origin !== "https://www.myfrontend.com") return;
  const frontEndWindow = e.source;
  const data = JSON.parse(e.data);
  const {funcToRun, args} = data;
  //TODO: SECURITY: 
  // Check syntax of funcToRun, args
  // Check funcToRun against list of available functions 
  // Check args are as expected 

  //TODO Add failureHandler
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(res => {
    console.log(res);
    const iframeWindow = document.querySelector('#myFrame').contentWindow;
    iframeWindow.postMessage(({type:'success',response:res}),"https://www.myfrontend.com")
  })[funcToRun](...args)
  },false)
</script>
<iframe 
  id="myFrame"
  src="https://www.myfrontend.com/#/home"
  style="width: 100%; height: 800px; border: none"
</iframe>
```

###### modal.gs

```
var htmlOutput = HtmlService
    .createHtmlOutputFromFile('modal.html'
    .setWidth(600)
    .setHeight(800);
SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(htmlOutput, 'My add-on');
```

###### frontEnd.com/index.html

```
window.parent.postMessage(
  (JSON.stringify({funcToRun: 'getData', args:[1,2]})), 
  'https://n-5fydpzckmar5yncflnjytuyfcusdcfogmgc2eti-1lu-script.googleusercontent.com')
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution. The parent URL is not always `https://n-5fydpzckmar5yncflnjytuyfcusdcfogmgc2eti-1lu-script.googleusercontent.com`, it could be for instance `https://n-5fydpzckmar5yncflnjytuyfcusdcfogmgc2eti-0lu-script.googleusercontent.com/`, etc. What can we do with `window.parent.postMessage` in `frontEnd.com/index.html`?

Comment: @SoftTimur You can use `*` as origin. But for better security, just ping `0lu`, `1lu`, `2lu` and so on.

Comment: I cannot make it work and posted another question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77594354/make-the-iframe-dialog-host-my-website-in-google-sheets-add-on. Do you have any idea?