# Make the iframe dialog host my website in Google Sheets add-on

Tags: nginx, google-apps-script, iframe, postmessage, google-workspace-add-ons

I'm making a Google Sheets add-on. The core of the Google Sheets add-on is a website hosted in a dialog. I'm trying to use [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77342503/702977) to host the website in the dialog and ensure the communication with the google sheet and the backend.

Here is `modal.html` in Google Apps Script:

```
<script>
window.addEventListener('message',e =>{
  if(e.origin !== "https://v10.10studio.tech") return;
  const frontEndWindow = e.source;
  const data = JSON.parse(e.data);
  const {funcToRun, args} = data;

  console.log("document.referrer", document.referrer);
  //TODO: SECURITY: 
  // Check syntax of funcToRun, args
  // Check funcToRun against list of available functions 
  // Check args are as expected 

  //TODO Add failureHandler
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(res => {
    console.log(res);
    const iframeWindow = document.querySelector('#myFrame').contentWindow;
    iframeWindow.postMessage(({type:'success',response:res}),"https://v10.10studio.tech")
  })[funcToRun](...args)
  },false)
</script>
<iframe 
  id="myFrame"
  src="https://v10.10studio.tech/#/message-sender"
  style="width: 100%; height: 800px; border: none">
</iframe>
```

`modal.gs`:

```
var htmlOutput = HtmlService
    .createHtmlOutputFromFile('modal.html'
    .setWidth(600)
    .setHeight(800);
SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(htmlOutput, 'My add-on');
```

When I test in and open the dialog, it shows an error: `Firefox Can’t Open This Page` and `To protect your security, v10.10studio.tech will not allow Firefox to display the page if another site has embedded it. To see this page, you need to open it in a new window.`

Here is the nginx configuration of v10.10studio.tech in the production server:

```
gzip on;
gzip_proxied any;
gzip_disable "msie6";
gzip_vary on;
gzip_proxied any;
gzip_comp_level 6;
gzip_buffers 16 8k;
gzip_http_version 1.1;
gzip_min_length 256;
gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript application/x-javascript text/xml >

upstream backend {
   server 178.62.87.71:443;
}

server {
    listen              443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate     /etc/letsencrypt/live/v10.10studio.tech/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/v10.10studio.tech/privkey.pem;
    server_name v10.10studio.tech;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_session_timeout 1d;
    ssl_stapling on;
    ssl_stapling_verify on;
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=15768000;
    add_header X-Frame-Options "ALLOW-FROM https://n-5fydpzckmar5yncflnjytuyfcusdcfogmgc2eti-0lu-script.g>
    add_header Content-Security-Policy "frame-ancestors https://n-5fydpzckmar5yncflnjytuyfcusdcfogmgc2eti>
    proxy_ssl_name "www.backend.io";
    proxy_ssl_server_name on;

    location ~ /socialLoginSuccess {
        rewrite ^ '/#/socialLoginSuccess' redirect;
    }

    location ~ /auth/(.*) {
        proxy_pass  https://backend/10studio/auth/$1?$query_string;
        proxy_set_header Host v10.10studio.tech;
    }

    location ~ ^/stripe_checkout/(.*)$ {
        return 302 https://checkout.stripe.com/pay/$1;
    }

    location ~ ^/stripe_billing/(.*)$ {
        return 302 https://billing.stripe.com/p/session/$1;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_set_header    Host                $host;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto   $scheme;
        proxy_set_header    Accept-Encoding     "";
        proxy_set_header    Proxy               "";
        proxy_pass          http://v10:8080/;

        # These three lines added as per https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/issues/1942 to remove sock>
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   Connection "upgrade";

        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Content-Type';
    }
}
```

And here are the screenshots of the NS_ERROR_XFO_VIOLATION:

[image]

[image]

Additionally, I notice that the domain of Google Sheets can be  `https://n-5fydpzckmar5yncflnjytuyfcusdcfogmgc2eti-0lu-script.googleusercontent.com` or `https://n-5fydpzckmar5yncflnjytuyfcusdcfogmgc2eti-1lu-script.googleusercontent.com`, etc. So we need to have a more general solution.

Does anyone know how to make the iframe open the website?

Comment: Does Xframeoptions  `ALLOW ALL` or CSP frame ancestors `*` work?

Comment: I'm getting this too in another domain and I can't figure out why. Chrome doesn't even flag it as an error, simply states "domain.blabla refused to connect". Firefox instead at least shows the NS_ERROR_XFO_VIOLATION in network column.